# How to create a table with a column that is able to store both decimal and fraction values?

Tags: sql, database, sqldatatypes

Firstly, I intended to **create a table of Movie**, that has MovieId, Title, ReleaseDate, and Rating as its columns using SQL syntax. And here are what I have done:

```
CREATE TABLE Movie (
    MovieId INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Titles VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ReleaseDate DATE,
    Ratings DECIMAL(3,2) CONSTRAINT check_rating CHECK (Ratings >= 0 AND Ratings <= 5)
)
```

But, it is demanded that the "Ratings" column also **can store fractions too**. How to make this data type also be feasible to store?

Comment: Isn't the `fraction` the two digits after the decimal point in DECIMAL(3,2)? so it does/can store fractions. For example 0.5.

Comment: What I mean by a fraction is a numerical value that has a numerator and denominator. For instance, "1/4", "2/3", etc. So, when anyone inserts to the database a fraction value, it automatically converts it to decimal, like "0.25", "0,67", etc.

Comment: This sounds like a capability you would have at the front-end (presentation layer). Most database products don't have a data-type capable of dealing with those fractions, only decimals. You maybe able to crate it as a varchar column, accept the expression and have a computed column with the decimal value calculated (or a trigger inserting /rejecting it), not in the same column. Happy to be proven wrong, though!

Comment: How are you going to use those values? Just for display, or to you want to calculate average/max/min?